# Installing dig on Debian

Tags: debian, dig

I've tried installing dig on Debian, but the apt-get utility doesn't seem to know what it is.

Is it part of some larger set of packages? Where can I find this?

Comment: Alternatively, you could use the Debian Package Website: https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages#search_contents

Answer (score 135, accepted):

On Ubuntu it's in `dnsutils`. It's the same in Debian.

Install it with:

```
apt-get install -y dnsutils
```

`apt-file` lets you search for files in packages even if they aren't installed.

Comment: for info : `apt-file -x find .*/dig$` because I tried `apt-file find dig` but got thousands of res. Then I tried harder when I saw your comment ^^